# force installation to connect global archive

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

when I try to install 18.04, no matter what I do, it keeps connecting to 'countrycode'.archive.ubuntu.com.

I don't want it to connect to some shitty server during installation. Is there any way to force it to connect to archive.ubuntu.com?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My, oh my. Language, please.

Comment: tr but I don't see how that's relevant

Comment: I chose los angeles as location and now it installs from US even with minimal installation. do I have to try all locations until I find global server?